# Parsing "original_score" from rotten tomatoes reviews

Tags: json, jupyter-notebook, rotten-tomatoes

So this might a very simple question.

I am trying to access a field called original_score in critic reviews and this field is available in some and not others.

```
{u'publication': u'Village Voice', u'links': u'quote': u'When teenaged Andy plops down on the grass to share his old toys with a shy little girl, the film spikes with sadness and layered pleasure -- a concise, deeply wise expression of the ephemeral that feels real and yet utterly transporting.', u'freshness': u'fresh', u'critic': u'Eric Hynes', u'date': u'2013-08-04'}
{u'publication': u'New Yorker', u'links':  u'quote': u'There are many sweet laughs and joking allusions to horror and prison-break movies, but the Pixar gang gets at the most primary fear -- being cast off and no longer of use.', u'freshness': u'fresh', u'critic': u'David Denby', u'date': u'2013-08-04'}
{u'publication': u'CNN.com', u'links': { u'quote': u'I seriously doubt there will be a more hilarious and heartfelt blockbuster all summer.', u'freshness': u'fresh', u'critic': u'Tom Charity', u'date': u'2013-08-04'}
{u'publication': u'TheWrap', u'links': { u'quote': u"It's still more inventive, clever and laugh-out-loud funny than any other movie out there now.", u'freshness': u'fresh', u'critic': u'Leah Rozen', u'date': u'2011-10-07'}
{u'publication': u'Time Out', u'links': {u'quote': u"The 'Toy Story' films are deservedly seen as the gold standard for computer-generated animation...", u'freshness': u'fresh', u'original_score': u'4/5', u'critic': u'Ben Walters', u'date': u'2010-07-15'}
```

For the items that appear in all the reviews, I can access them using:

```
data = data['reviews']
    data = [dict(fresh=r['freshness'], 
                 quote=r['quote'], 
                 critic=r['critic'], 
                 publication=r['publication'], 
                 review_date=r['date'],
                 imdb=imdb, rtid=rtid
                 ) 
                    for r in data]
```

How do I access originial_score and assign a null to the reviews which don't have any?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the ternary expression to assign a value to original_score:

```
original_score = r['original_score'] if 'original_score' in r.keys() else None
```

In that vein:

```
data = [dict(fresh=r['freshness'], 
             quote=r['quote'], 
             critic=r['critic'], 
             publication=r['publication'], 
             review_date=r['date'],
             imdb=imdb, rtid=rtid,
             original_score = r['original_score'] if 'original_score' in r.keys() else None) 
                for r in data]
```